# Fast PWM: Resolution in hertz

Tags: pwm, dac

I am trying to get a nice sounding varying PWM to DAC, and intend to use a [Sallen Key](http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/OPstool.php) as part of an active low pass filter.

I set the Fast PWM at a max of 255 ([WGM1[0-3] = 5](http://sculland.com/ATmega168/Interrupts-And-Timers/16-Bit-Timer-Setup/)) and set/clear OC1A upon comparing with OCR1A `(1<< COM1A1)`

I also update the value of OCR1A in 64 distinct steps, changing those steps around 15'000 times a second to create a specific sinusoidal shape.

As the chip works at 16 Mega Hertz, does this mean that one cycle of PWM is `16'000'000/256=` 62.5 Kilo Hertz? If not, what is its resolution

Thank you!

Comment: As you are directly poking into the hardware I/O registers, you have to read [the datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/ATmega48A-PA-88A-PA-168A-PA-328-P-DS-DS40002061B.pdf). Look for the prescaler, and the bits CS1[0-2].

Comment: Assuming you have no prescaler, you'd indeed get around 62.5kHz. The 15kHz update rate for the sinusoidal is a bit odd, as it's 1/4.167 of the PWM update frequency. I'd probably use the timers interrupt to call a function that updates OC1A every 4th call.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers! I read the datasheet but I guess without prescalers it's indeed 62.5kHz. The update will vary considerably as I'm trying to do the 12 tones of the scale. If I were to update OC1A every 4th PWM I'm not sure I'd be able to do a perfect period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of the comments, I decided to use variable PWM max values to match absolutely with the frequency. This resulted in a crispier sound that *actually doesn't need the Sallen Key anymore*.

For example, a low C natural, or `261.6Hz`, updated `32` times for `8` full cycles of PWM give us, for a 16MHz chip, an period and amplitude of `238`.

This means that having a prescaler of `8` (`CS01`), a period (`OCR0A`) AND a max potential duty cycle (`ICR1`) of `238`, and going through 32 iterations of the sound sought for, I got the sound that I wanted and none of the wave groove that comes with a pulse duty cycle cut short.

Sure, it means less granularity when it comes to a Bb with a max duty cycle of 133, however it worked for me.